# Name of anime which is about a fugitive princess who controls a mecha

Tags: neppu-kairiku-bushi-road

Okay, so I'm trying so hard but I cannot remember this for the life of me...

- It's a movie that's relatively new and probably around 2005-2013
- Genre: Mecha
- A princess is on the run and controls a mecha
- Princess' mother was killed in a coup d'tat
- Boy whom she finds has white hair and blue eyes and is a really good fighter
- At the end of the movie, there is huge fight with a mega mecha that everyone assumed was a myth
- In order to use the mecha, it has to stab you in the throat
- It has a sad ending cause both the main characters die

Answer (score 7):

Neppu Kairiku Bushi Road

[image: Neppu Kairiku Bushi Road]

Sounds a lot like this anime and it is from 2013 but the boy did not die, only the girl did. But that was in the after-credits scene so its possible you did not see it. The robot did stab the girl in the throat and it was considered a myth.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neppu_Kairiku_Bushi_Road):

> The story takes place in a time when the world is in the pits of despair after being ravaged by a poison called "shinobi" that came to earth via an asteroid. The people run away to the place called "Kairiku," a place that used to be the bottom of the ocean. Here, the people try and protect themselves against the effects of the poison. In such a world, there was a single light of hope. The "Holy Weapon Giga Road" and the legendary warrior "Yagyuu" are needed in order to counter the effects of the poison. Ame, a princess of a fallen nation, stands up in order to save the world.

Ame: The main girl

> A former princess/priestess of the country Ise.
>   Her mother is dead because of a shinobi. She travels with companions and a key to finding a weapon built by men who put an end to the shinobi. She has romantic feelings for Suou. She disappeared in the end.

Comment: Would you mind perhaps giving a few more details (perhap by copying a summary from elsewhere) to indicate to the OP why you think this is it? See [this](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/1103/2604) for some guidelines.

Comment: I hope this is good enough.